# Birt chart ignoring data older than one year

Tags: mongodb, birt

I have data from a MongoDB data source and set. they have multiple fields and a date field. I did a line chart to show one of the fields by date. The date is on the X axis and the date is a "Day of year" value.
So everything was going well until i had 1 year old data. The old data is not on the chart, but i know it's there because it's on a crosstab from the same datacube showing the same data.

How can i show all the data i queried from MongoDB on the chart?

My X-axis proprety are:

`Is category Axis: yes
Type: DateTime
Origin: min
Scale -> step: auto (It's blocked)`

Thanks

Comment: How and where do you compute the "Day of year" value? In Eclipse designer i don't see a such function in "Grouping" option of the x-axis chart, nore in native birt datetime functions. Are you sure  that both years are not aggregated on these Days of years?

Comment: It's from an ISODate field from a MongoDB document, I use it in a data cube as a "group" (dimension). It gives me many options, like "day of year", "day of week", "day of month", etc.

Comment: I don't tink it's aggregated because i can have different days, if it's more than a year appart, the older one is not showed.
I get, for the dates 2013-08-01 and 2014-09-01, only the 2014-09-01 is showed. Also, the old data is in the array I did with the same data cube the chart is made from